# Можно ли как-то ускорить эту реализацию алгоритма Дейкстры?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, графы

Моя реализация класса "граф", метод **PathWeights** реализует алгоритм Дейкстры для ориентированного взвешенного графа:

```
const int HUGE_NUMBER = 100000000; //

typedef std::pair<int, uint64_t> Arrow;

bool ArrowCmp(const Arrow &lhs, const Arrow &rhs) {
  return lhs.first < rhs.first;
}

class Graph {
  int size_;

  std::vector<std::vector<Arrow>> arrows;
  std::vector<int> parents;

 public:
  explicit Graph(int size) {
    size_ = size;
    arrows.resize(size);
    parents.resize(size);
  }

  void AddEdge(int from, int to, uint64_t cost) {
    if (from == to) {
      return;
    }

    auto arrow = std::make_pair(to, cost);

    auto pos = std::lower_bound(arrows[from].begin(),
                                arrows[from].end(),
                                arrow,
                                ArrowCmp);

    if (pos == arrows[from].end()) {
      arrows[from].push_back(arrow);
    } else if (pos->first != arrow.first) {
      arrows[from].insert(pos, arrow);
    } else {
      (*pos).second = std::min(cost, pos->second);
    }
  }

  std::vector<int> Path(int from, int to) {
    PathWeights(from);

    std::vector<int> ret;

    for (int cv = to; cv != from; cv = parents[cv]) {
      ret.push_back(cv);
    }

    ret.push_back(from);
    std::reverse(ret.begin(), ret.end());

    return ret;
  }

  std::vector<uint64_t> PathWeights(int start) {
    std::vector<uint64_t> lens(size_);

    std::fill(lens.begin(), lens.end(), HUGE_NUMBER);
    lens[start] = 0;

    int count = 0;

    std::set<std::pair<uint64_t, int>> sorted_ps;

    sorted_ps.insert(std::make_pair(0, start));

    while (!sorted_ps.empty()) {
      int from = sorted_ps.begin()->second;
      sorted_ps.erase(sorted_ps.begin());

      for (int to = 0; to < size_; ++to) {
        auto arrow = std::make_pair(to, 0ul);
        auto pos = std::lower_bound(arrows[from].begin(),
                                    arrows[from].end(),
                                    arrow,
                                    ArrowCmp);

        if (pos == arrows[from].end()) {
          continue;
        }

        if (pos->first != to) {
          continue;
        }

        auto cost = pos->second;

        if (lens[from] + cost < lens[to]) {
          sorted_ps.erase(std::make_pair(lens[to], to));
          lens[to] = lens[from] + cost;
          parents[from] = to;
          sorted_ps.insert(std::make_pair(lens[to], to));
        }
      }
      ++count;
    }

    return lens;
  }
};
```

Я пытаюсь решить задачу из закрытого контеста, условие задачи можно сформулировать так:

1. Дан ориентированный взвешанный граф, в котором могут быть петли и кратные ребра
2. Веса - целые числа от нуля до двух
3. Вершин меньше 5000, ребер меньше 20000
4. Нужно найти вес самого легкого пути между двумя данными вершинами
5. В main не больше 10000 вызовов **PathWeights**
6. Программа должна использовать не больше 64Mb памяти, работать не дольше 3 секунд

Сейчас программа работает верно, но медленно.

Первое решение хранило ребра в виде матрицы смежности, а подходящую вершину искало линейным поиском, использую булевый массив. Сейчас я использую вектор исходящих ребер, отсортированныц по возрастанию индекса конечной вершины, и set для выбора подходящей вершины. Можно ли как-то еще ускорить это решение? Стоит ли при этих условиях использовать другой алгоримт?

Comment: Не пробовали написать алгоритм Флойда? Кажется, что его можно запихнуть в три секунды на таких ограничениях.

Comment: `Вершин меньше 5000, ребер меньше 20000` - значит, графы с большим количество вершин разреженные, для таких есть специальные методы с лучшей асимптотикой

Comment: Не подскажете, в какую сторону гуглить? Я пока ничего не смог найти

Comment: [Вот, например](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/dijkstra_sparse). Правда, с петлями и кратными рёбрам я дела не имел, но для решёточного графа 2.5 миллиона узлов за 1.3 с обрабатывалось ([пример на Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22376696/844416))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На всякий случай, значительно повысить производительность позволила следующая мысль:

1. Расстояние L до той вершины, которая сейчас обрабатывается, больше или равно всем предыдущим расстояниям
2. Новое минимальное расстояние находится во множестве {L, L+1, L+1}.

Это позволяет отказаться от сета и использовать три вектора, каждый для своего расстояния, а новую вершину получать c помощью `.end(); .pop_back()`, кажется, что это упрощает O(V+E log E) до O(V+E).

Answer (score 2):

С вот этим местом явно что-то не так:

```
   for (int to = 0; to < size_; ++to) {
     auto arrow = std::make_pair(to, 0ul);
     auto pos = std::lower_bound(arrows[from].begin(),
                                 arrows[from].end(),
                                 arrow,
                                 ArrowCmp);
```

Имеем линейный проход по *всем* вершинам графа, плюс ещё бинпоиск, а тут достаточно было проитерироваться по всем парам в `arrows[from]`. Это явно основная проблема этого кода в плане временной сложности.

Ещё заметил строчку `parents[from] = to;` - точно не наоборот?

Также советую побенчмаркать AddEdge. У меня смутное подозрение, что все эти манипуляции со вставкой в середину вектора могут нехило ухудшить производительность. Мне вообще никогда не приходилось в списках рёбер поддерживать инвариант "исходящие рёбра отсортированы". Возможно, лучше от него избавиться? Зачем он здесь?

Comment: В AddEdge, по идее, все эти фокусы нужны для того, чтобы хранить только самое короткое из кратных ребер, но я проверил, если все заменить на `push_back`, лучше не становится

Comment: Да, вы правы, цикл остался от матрицы смежности, если его убрать, становится сильно быстрее: тот тест, который раньше занимал 3.077s, теперь отрабатывает за 181ms

Comment: Обидно, что даже с таким ускорением программа все равно работает дольше трех  секунд на поздних тестах